# Changing the strings "chem" to "drug" in Fallout and Fallout 2

Tags: mods, fallout, fallout-2

I've been trying to get the most authentic Fallout experience; and one of the things I remember hearing about is changing the string "drug" to "chem" in Fallout and Fallout 2. I'd like to change the strings back, but I don't know how to modify game data myself (ideally with a few tools as possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could open up the game's data files in a hex editor and change the text from "chem" to "drug" because they're both four characters, that should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately the files are not in any format I'm familiar with. The file utility on Ubuntu can't find a signature for the file. I'm given to understand that there is some magic file format in play.

Comment: I think that what McKay intended, was to open the binary file in a hex editor. These types of editors give insight into mysterious binary files by, among various tricks, revealing strings hidden within them.

Comment: I ran strings on it to no avail; but I have good news I tripped across an embarrassingly good document: http://falloutmods.wikia.com/wiki/DAT_file_format

Comment: A few years too late, but be careful! Doing something like this can change text like "chemical" into "drugical"